# IIS Url redirect match pattern

Tags: url, iis, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I am redirecting URL in the config file. This is what I am doing:

```
<rule name="award temp redirect"  stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*?)/?award.aspx$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.abc.com.au/award.aspx" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

This is working fine for `/award.aspx` but I want to add for `/awards` or `/award` as well. Currently I have create separate rules for `/awards` or `/award`.

Can I add these two into one match. If the Url is `/award.aspx` or `/award` or `/awards` then redirect to `http://www.abc.com.au/award.aspx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` accept regex for `url` value. Try:

```
<match url="(.*?)/?awards?(\.aspx)?$" />
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This will match `award`, `award.aspx`, `awards` and `awards.aspx`.

**Update** to match `/test` as well:

```
<match url="(.*?)/?(awards?|test)(\.aspx)?$" />
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It is just a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). You can match whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks what if i want to add testaward or testaward.aspx as well

Comment: Sorry its not testawards i want to match its /test or /test.aspx sorry for the confusion @lorond